# REST API filter by a "BusinessData" field

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a query that brings the contents of a list based on a query like this:

```
https://myserver.com/LibraryABC/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=*,FileLeafRef&$filter=(MyField eq '700095')
```

This was working before some changes that were made in Sharepoint. Now the same causes the following error:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="es-ES">
No se puede usar el campo "MyField" de tipo "BusinessData" en la expresión de filtro de consulta.
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

The error message translation would be something like this:

> The field "MyField" of type "BusinessData" cannot be used in an
>   expression of filter or query.

I think they have changed the field to update it from an external source (not sure) so it cannot be queried. Exists some way to overcome this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the field type of `MyField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't use **External Data** field in REST API **$filter**.

As a workaround, we can use CAML Query and REST API to instead it.

The method below for your reference:

```
function getDataWithCaml(listName, caml) {
    var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+ listName + "')/GetItems";
    var requestData = { "query" :
           {"__metadata": 
              { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }
              , "ViewXml": caml
           }
        };
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    });
}
```

Refer to: [Using CAML with SharePoint REST API](http://Using%20CAML%20with%20SharePoint%20REST%20API)